# How to increase chance of two random numbers between 1 and 20 to be the same

Tags: java

How to increase chance of two random numbers between 1 and 20 to be the same

```
int x=rand.nextInt(20)+1;
int y=rand.nextInt(20)+1;
```

Comment: By creating your own definition of "random" and implementing an algorithm for it?  What have you tried?  What didn't work?

Comment: Unless you're using a poor generator, they should be roughly the same

Comment: I used java.util.Random

Comment: @programmerwannabe: Ok, and what exactly was the problem?  `java.util.Random` generates a random number.  What isn't working for you?

Comment: The chance of the two numbers being the same is 1/20 (insofar as the random number generator draws from a uniform distribution). You can't change that.

Comment: @AndyTurner I mean... to be fair, "Random" is not the same as "Random, independent and fairly distributed." It is super unclear what he's asking, though.

Comment: I want numbers to be difrent but dont want to wait to long to get match

Comment: Define "increase the chances"... like, you want the chance of them matching to be more than 1 in 20?

Comment: @programmerwannabe what do you mean "wait long"? If you generate 21 numbers, you are *guaranteed* to have generated the same number at least twice; but you are more likely than not to have generated the same number twice after around 5 goes.

Comment: @programmerwannabe: `"I want numbers to be difrent but dont want to wait to long to get match"` - If the numbers are different then by definition they won't match.  Please, take at least a moment of your time and actually explain what you're talking about.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think he means have the two match each other, in which case there is no guarantee.

Comment: @programmerwannabe the answer given below gives a solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

One naïve way to do it would be to generate two random numbers between 1 and 10, and then just double them.  Or 1 and 5 and quadruple them.  The possibilities are endless!

But then you'll be missing a few numbers (i.e. the first method cannot produce an 11), so from there you can generate a *second* random number and just add it to both.

For example:

```
int x=rand.nextInt(10)+1;
int y=rand.nextInt(10)+1;

int offset = rand.nextInt(10)+1;

x += offset;
y += offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

True random numbers will have repetitions and the nextInt() method does that, but it's also possible to do what you want though I hardly call it random.

```
public Stack<Integer> rand(){
    Stack<Integer> numbers = new Stack<>();
    for (int i=1;i<=20;i++){
        numbers.push(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    return numbers;
}
public int nextInt(Stack<Integer> numbers){
    if (numbers.empty()){
        Collections.copy(numbers,rand());
        return numbers.pop();
    }
    return numbers.pop();
}

Stack<Integer> numbers = rand();
int rand1 = nextInt(numbers);
int rand2 = nextInt(numbers);
```